# Accelerometer Data keeps on fluctuating

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer

I keep my phone at same place in wooden floor.But the value keeps on changing every time I call the below code snippet

```
if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {                    
    let z:String="x:"+String(accelerometerData.acceleration.x)+" y:"+String(accelerometerData.acceleration.y)+"z"+String(accelerometerData.acceleration.z)
    print("\(z)")               
}
```

Here is the code that I used to initialize and kick start the accelerometer

```
//Accelerometer
motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How much are the fluctuations?

Comment: Yes it does. Why is that a problem?

Comment: But it should give same values for same position right ... I have to pass the accelerometer positions to API.. If it keeps on changing which value shall I give ? any value that I receive at the time or find mean value of 5 attempts and pass that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, When you use Accelerometer only, there is earth's gravity which influences z value of accelerometer. But DeviceMotion tries to compensate for this influence of gravity (i.e.tries to give more accurate value of acceleration.z) by performing some algorithm on raw data received from sensor.

But this algorithm is not 100% accurate and that is why even if you put your device on flat surface like table, you get some non-zero value. This inaccuracy is very low in percentage but still you will get result which cannot be simply ignored.

You may want to perform enough trials and get average values of them to compensate for it. Again, this average value will not solve the problem completely. For example, when device is moving(and not stable such when on table) you may get more inaccurate values.